# AWS S3 file uploads: PHP SDK vs REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to upload a file to AWS Simple Storage Service from a PHP script. The script gets called from an external program and for some unknown reason the script bombs out as soon as I load the AWS PHP SDK. I've tried everything to get it to work without any success. I'm therefore thinking of rather using the AWS S3 REST API to upload the file.

My question is, what is the major drawback of using the REST API compared to the PHP SDK? I know it will be a bit harder to use the REST APIs, but if I only need to upload files to S3, would it take significantly more time? Or would it be worth spending another half a day (hopefully) trying to get the script to run while using the SDK?

Comment: Hard to really answer that question.  Different developers may have different experience level so hard to gauge where your time investment is best spent. I personally would be looking at the logs to try to understand the failure behavior and would favor working with the provided SDK because maybe today you only need S3, but some day you might need other AWS services and having a working SDK in your environment would be pretty important.

Comment: The PHP SDK uses the REST API. Writing your own implementation, even just to do uploads to S3, is non-trivial, especially if you want to capture all of S3 idiosyncrasies (signing the request with your AWS keys, handling the expect header, handling network-level errors, putting the bucket in the correct place in the URL, etc.)

Comment: I'd check to make sure your environment meets the minimum requirements: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/requirements.html

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I think I'll take another swing at getting the SDK to work.